# How to use pivot_wider keeping each duplicate separate

Tags: r, tidyr

How to pivot_wider this small dataset? I want to put the race as
column headers with each Count but for an unknown reason it puts all the
Counts into a list. Also getting the warning below:

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- structure(list(Count = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3), race = c("L", "F", "W", "F", "F", "LF", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "S", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F"), year = c("2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

a
 Count race year
1      1    L 2012
2      1    F 2013
3      3    W 2013
4      1    F 2013
5      2    F 2013
6      1   LF 2013
7      2    F 2013
8      1    F 2012
9      3    F 2013
10     1    F 2013
11     1    F 2012
12     2    F 2013
13     2    F 2013
14     1    S 2013
15     3    F 2013
16     3    F 2013
17     3    F 2013
18     5    F 2013
19     3    F 2013
20     3    F 2013

a %>% pivot_wider(names_from = race, values_from = Count)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  year  L         F          W         LF        S        
  <chr> <list>    <list>     <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 2012  <dbl [1]> <dbl [2]>  <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
2 2013  <NULL>    <dbl [14]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>


     Warning message:
Values from `Count` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
* Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
  {data} %>%
  dplyr::group_by(year, race) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  dplyr::filter(n > 1L)
```

**EDITED: Expected output**

```
year  L         F          W         LF        S        
  2012  1         1          0          0        0   
  2012  0         1          0          0        0
  2013  0         1          3          1        0
  2013  0         1          0          0        0
  2013 ...       ...        ...        ...      ...
  2013 ...       ...        ...        ...      ...
  2013 ...       ...        ...        ...      ...
  2013  0         3          0          0        0     
  2013 ...       ...        ...        ...      ...
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Yes, for the many 2013 F entries, do you want the sum of Count, or a concatenation of them, or 14 F columns, or more rows, or something else? If the first, add values_fn = sum into your pivot_wider step.

Comment: I don't want to values added, I just want 14 rows of each individual "Count" under F, LF, W, S, L columns. See the expected output above under EDITED:

Comment: Running `dplyr::count(a, race, year)` reveals that with this sample `a`, you have 2 `F, 2012` and 14 `F, 2013`. Which of the duplicate rows there do you wish to discard? Or do you want to summarize (`sum`?)` per group? The warning/error is clear, you don't have a 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: I want all of my  values under "Count" to be listed the same way. The only thing I want is "race" values to be named as columns with their corresponding "Count" values. For some reason `pivot_wider` is applying `sum` to these values.

Comment: I don't want to discard any values. I want the Count values from `a` under each corresponding column L, F, LF, W, and S.

Comment: "for an unknown reason" - the reason is that there is no unique identifier per row so when you try to transform to wide, `pivot_wider` doesn't know what to do with multiple Count values per year-race combination. One solution is to create a new identifier, as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, you want something like below.  Since you don't want the multiple observations for each `race`-`year` pair to be combined or aggregated in any way, you can make a new variable (I called it `obs`) that is the observation number within `race`-`year` pair and thus this variable will keep those values separate rather than trying to combine or aggregate them.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
a <- structure(list(Count = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3), race = c("L", "F", "W", "F", "F", "LF", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "S", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F"), year = c("2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

a %>% 
  group_by(race, year) %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "race", values_from="Count", values_fill=0) %>% 
  arrange(year, obs) %>% 
  select(-obs)
#> # A tibble: 16 × 6
#> # Groups:   year [2]
#>    year      L     F     W    LF     S
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2012      1     1     0     0     0
#>  2 2012      0     1     0     0     0
#>  3 2013      0     1     3     1     1
#>  4 2013      0     1     0     0     0
#>  5 2013      0     2     0     0     0
#>  6 2013      0     2     0     0     0
#>  7 2013      0     3     0     0     0
#>  8 2013      0     1     0     0     0
#>  9 2013      0     2     0     0     0
#> 10 2013      0     2     0     0     0
#> 11 2013      0     3     0     0     0
#> 12 2013      0     3     0     0     0
#> 13 2013      0     3     0     0     0
#> 14 2013      0     5     0     0     0
#> 15 2013      0     3     0     0     0
#> 16 2013      0     3     0     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Exactly what I needed @DaveArmstrong. I have used pivot_wider before and It seemed pretty straightforward. Thanks Dave